# Just Upgraded My Server : 8 to 16 GB Ram, 4 to 6 CPU - How to allocate new resources?

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I've been searching all over for magento config posts and digesting them, but haven't found anything like what I'm asking for.

I've just upgraded my VPS with more resources, so my server still has it's old config resource allocation setup for MYSQL, PHP (7.2), Cacheing, Apache, etc.

I was wondering could you please let me know all the settings on my WHM CentOS server I should now change so that my Magento 1.9.3.10 system is making the most out of the new resources?

(If you could give me specific values for my new resources I would love you even more! :)  )

I have a small magento store with less than 30 products.
With average 300 users per day.

I also run all the usual WHM stuff like exim, munin, etc. on the server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: If you could post any of the additional information requested, some Suggestions could be made available for you to consider.